# Send put request from angularjs to laravel

Tags: angularjs, rest, laravel

I'm trying to send a put request by angularjs. My app receptor is running laravel. 
When I trying send the request, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property '_method' of undefined
    at $http.transformRequest (http://localhost:8000/js/controller-university.js:91:28)
    at transformData (http://localhost:8000/js/libs/angular/angular.js:7433:12)
    at serverRequest (http://localhost:8000/js/libs/angular/angular.js:8071:23)
    at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:8000/js/libs/angular/angular.js:11572:81)
    at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:8000/js/libs/angular/angular.js:11572:81)
    at http://localhost:8000/js/libs/angular/angular.js:11658:26
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8000/js/libs/angular/angular.js:12701:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:8000/js/libs/angular/angular.js:12513:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8000/js/libs/angular/angular.js:12805:24)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/js/libs/angular/angular.js:19139:23)
```

Here my code:

```
  update : function(data) {
    return $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/api/university'+data.id,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      data: $.param(data)
      transformRequest: function(data){
          data._method = 'PUT';
          return data;
      }
    });
  },
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here the correct code:

```
       update: function(data){
          return $http({
            method: 'PUT', 
            url: '/api/university/'+data.id, 
            data: $.param(data), 
            headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
          });
        },
```

Comment: What does the $.param() function do, and can you send a link to it's documentation? I am trying to use this, but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = {
    method: 'put',
    url: '/admin/banners/'+$scope.editid,
    data: fields,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    }
};
```

It worked for me.